# Eldoc breaks word

Tags: echo-area, eldoc

I use Eglot and find the word-breaking sometimes annoying:

[image]

How to avoid word-breaking?

Comment: Is this with `visual-line-mode`?

Comment: @Drew: `visual-line-mode` is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current solution:

```lisp
;; init.el
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Echo Area 0*" "no hooks")
  (setq-local word-wrap t))
```

Note that *echo area* and *minibuffer* are two different concepts, so `minibuffer-*-hook` doesn't help here.

(Dont know whether the `"no hooks"` is necessary.)